# Do not find the element in the webpage

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

1. Can not find the element
2. The code was writen using python with visual studio code

```
from time import time
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
paginaHit = 'https://hit.com.do/solicitud-de-verificacion/'
driver.get(paginaHit)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

bl = 'SMLU7318830A'
elementoBL = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="billoflanding"]').send_keys(bl)
# WebDriverWait(driver,2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "bl"))).Click()
```

The code is OK, but can not find the element in the webpage.

Comment: "billoflading" maybe? Include HTML markup of the element you are targetting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The portion of the page you are trying to access is inside an EMBED tag. It looks similar to an IFRAME so I would start by switching the context to the EMBED tag and then try searching for the element.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
paginaHit = 'https://hit.com.do/solicitud-de-verificacion/'
driver.get(paginaHit)
driver.maximize_window()
embed = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "embed")
driver.switch_to.frame(embed)
bl = 'SMLU7318830A'
wait =WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "billoflanding"))).send_keys(bl)
```

Couple of additional points:

1. Don't use sleeps... sleeps are a bad practice. Instead use `WebDriverWait` when you need to wait for something to happen.
2. If you are using an ID to find an element, use `By.ID` and not XPath. ID should be preferred, when available. Next should be a CSS selector and then finally, XPATH only when needed, e.g. to locate elements by contained text or to do complicated DOM traversal.

Comment: Hey JeffC thank you so much.  De veras te lo agradezco mucho, personas como tu hacen del mundo un mejor lugar porque transfieren el alimento mas importante para el progreso que es el conocimiento, te reitero mi gratitud y admiración por tomarte tiempo para ayudar a un desconocido.

Comment: If this or any other answer was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.